# XSLT include

Tags: xslt

Сейчас у меня в xslt файле есть строка:

```
<xsl:include href="/xslt/file.xslt" />
```

Можно ли сделать, чтобы если у файла есть параметр, то подключался файл file.xslt, а если параметра нет, то файл file2.xslt?
Пробовал так, но не работает...

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable">
        <xsl:include href="/xslt/file.xslt" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:include href="/xslt/file2.xslt" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `<xsl:if>` конструкцию.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переменную `$variable` сравнивать с каким-нибудь значением. Заведите, к примеру, пустую переменную и сравнивайте `$variable` с нею, или просто `$variable = ''`.

Comment: не помогло :(

Comment: @gooda, как определена переменная `$variable`?

Answer (score -1):

Нет. Родительским элементом для `xsl:include` может быть только `xsl:stylesheet`